# UML class diagram associations

Tags: uml, class-diagram

In UML class diagrams, I am told we should not have any standalone classes but that they should all be connected in some way. In theory that makes sense and with simple classes, sure.. take the following for example:

[image]

So, a `Person` can have 0 or more of `Car`... Fair enough.. but now take the following example:

[image]

The `Person` and `PersonRepository` are not really connected in the sense that a `Person` can belong to a `PersonRepository` or that a `PersonRepository` has a `Person`. They are associated in that the `PersonRepository` will return a `Person` for the given `ID` however. So, is it correct to add an association line between them and if so, which way should it point? I am getting conflicting info about this situation. I'd appreciate any clarification given on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when instances of some class *belong to* instances of another class, it is an aggregation or composition relationship (which are special kinds of association).

If you can get a `Person` from a `PersonRepository` it is an association. Note that a repository may have more than one `Person`, so it has to be `1..n` on the `Person` end.

An arrow on the association end represents that this end is *navigable*: you can go from instances of the class on the other end, to instances of the class in the end with an arrow. In your example, you can go from instances of `Person` to the `PersonRepository` (e.g.: `person.getRepository()`) but you cannot get instances of `Person` from the `PersonRepository`. **The arrow should be on the other end**.

```
        1..n     1
Person <----------- PersonRepository
```

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Thank you.